# Blazor WebAssembly and Azure AD: AADSTS650052 error

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor-webassembly

Good day everyone

I'm having a trouble on my Blazor WebAssembly Project which I configured the authentication using the Azure AD, I set the Authentication's Supported account types to "**Account in this organizational directory only (Our Company Name only - Single Tenant) but I'm having this error below.**"

> "AADSTS650052: The app is trying to access a service ''(Ercenk SaaS
> SPA) that your organization '' lacks a service principal for. Contact
> your IT Admin to review the configuration of your service
> subscriptions or consent to the application in order to create the
> required service principal."

I'm currently on idea what to do, I tried to set it to "**Any Azure AD Directory - Multitenant**"

I hope someone can help me on this, it's my first time doing this authentication.

Thanks and regards

I tried to set it to "**Any Azure AD Directory - Multitenant**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error **"*AADSTS650052: The app is trying to access a service that your organization lacks a service principal for. Contact your IT Admin to review the configuration of your service subscriptions or consent to the application in order to create the required service principal*"** usually occurs if the Service Principal is missing for the Azure AD Application created.

- AAD determines whether a Service Principal exists for Client when the user attempts to log in. When none are found, it determines whether the client is a multi-tenant.
- Then, AAD verifies that all of the Service Principals for the APIs the Client want access to are present.

I created an **Azure AD Application**:

[image]

To create Azure AD Service Principal, you can make use of [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) like below:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals
Content-type: application/json

{
  "appId": "APPID"
}
```

[image]

The **Service Principal** got created successfully:

[image]

For ***sample***, I used the **authorization endpoint** like below:

[image]

[image]

***If still issue persists***, Add a client application in the Expose an API tab like below:

[image]

- AAD determines whether Client is a known client application to each API in the case of those that don't exist.
- Authentication fails if none of them list Client as a known client app.
- AAD then checks the required API access for those for which a Service Principal is missing.
- Fail authentication occurs if any required permission is found targeting an API for which no Service Principal exists.

**References:**

[Azure Active Directory Multi Tenant App Lacks Service Principal For New Tenant Error - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74093639/azure-active-directory-multi-tenant-app-lacks-service-principal-for-new-tenant-e) by SoySolisCarlos

[Create serviceprincipal - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-serviceprincipals?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)